# is there a way to create a graph in an SSRS report where the user can choose between ranges of a variable?

Tags: reporting-services, graph, ssrs-2008, report

Basically I need to show the trend of executions of a program over time where a user can select if they want to see month/week/daily/hourly data.

So I have a table called ProgramExecutions with the following columns:

```
ProgramName |  StartDate          | Enddate
------------+---------------------+--------------------
Windows     | 14/10/2015 16:10:00 | 14/10/2015 16:15:00  
Windows     | 13/10/2015 16:10:00 | 13/10/2015 16:15:00      
Windows     | 12/10/2015 16:10:00 | 12/10/2015 16:15:00      
Linux       | 14/10/2015 16:10:00 | 14/10/2015 16:15:00  
Linux       | 13/10/2015 16:10:00 | 13/10/2015 16:15:00      
Linux       | 12/10/2015 16:10:00 | 12/10/2015 16:15:00
```

I then have the following query that runs against this table

```
 Select Distinct ProgramName 
 AVG(DATEDIFF(ss,StartDate,Enddate)) as AvgSec,
 MAX(DATEDIFF(ss,TimeStart,TimeEnd))as MaxSec,
 MIN(DATEDIFF(ss,TimeStart,TimeEnd))as MinSec,
 Count(*) as NumberOfRuns
 From ProgramExecutions WITH(NOLOCK)
 Group By ProgramName
 Order By AVG(DATEDIFF(ss,TimeStart,TimeEnd))DESC;
```

How would I be able  to present what I am asking for in an SSRS report with the information that I have?

Comment: Basically so far I was able to count the number of executions for each program , however I am only given a start date and an end date for when the program ran. So i was wondering how I would be able to translate that into showing the amount of executions over a period of time and how I could represent that in a chart  where the user can select the length of the time period being represented.

Comment: could you edit your question to provide the code/program you have so far. This will help others pick up your question better

Comment: Would this help? Im still really bad at formatting questions on stackoverflow so apologies for that

Comment: better now, always try to provide concise but all the relevant information that others may require to answer your questions. Look at other similar question and you will get the hang of the formatting. Once again, welcome to StackOverflow !

Comment: Thanks Akshat Agarwal :)

Comment: Is this still a problem you are trying to solve?  I assume you would like a chart format which shows a variety of timescales based on a parameter?  Will the report always include the current time, or will it be able to show historic months?  Do you need all the data for one hour grouped into a single value, or are you expecting to be able to show how this changes over time?

Comment: Thank you for your interest Jonnus , i forgot to come back here and post my solution once i found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ve actually managed to solve this by creating a parameter called Timeframe and giving it 4 specific values : Hourly, Daily, Weekly, Monthly and created 4 different graphs that are triggered to become visible accordingly. This was the best solution I could come  up with and it works.